# More than one copy of React in the same app?|

Tags: reactjs

When I run npm ls react in the terminal, I get this:

```
├─┬ @testing-library/react@13.4.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-dom@18.2.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-scripts@5.0.1
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
└── react@18.2.0
```

Does that mean I have two versions of react? How do I fix it?

Comment: When you see that .. It means that it was de-duplicated ..  You CAN try to figure it out .. But --  The system already de-duplicated it for you.  Lot of node modules include dependencies that will be duplicated.  Unless it's causing super long build times or dependency errors in the console .. I usually ignore ..

Comment: No. It means that react-scripts, react-dom, etc, have a dependency on React. Instead of all of them downloading their own copy of it, it is deduped into one.